# Editing htaccess to not redirect if only domain is in the url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have my .htaccess redirecting when someone types /5 or something, but how do I make it not redirect if they just type domain?

So southeast.tv/5/e will redirect,
but southeast.tv will simply stay as southeast.tv

Here is my code now:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ http://southeast.tv/index.php?v=$1&t=$2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `RewriteCond` to negate requests to `/` only with `^[/]?$`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Only rewrite if the request is not for `/` The ? probably isn't needed
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !^[/]?$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ http://southeast.tv/index.php?v=$1&t=$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: `!^$` would be enough. Only very old apache versions need a leading slash.

Comment: For some reason it's still redirecting. Except now instead of an empty $1 it has: index.html.var